# Нужно изменить цвет ActionBar, а файла styles.xml у меня нет. Я пытался изменить в themes.xml через ColorPrimary, но менялся только цвет кнопок

Tags: android-toolbar, actionbar

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Germeteo" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#6495ED</item>
    </style>

<style name="Theme.Germeteo" parent="Base.Theme.Germeteo" />
```